# Rename all selected NLA tracks with the name of the actions they are holding

Tags: python, animation, scripting, nla-editor, actions

Is there a way to automatically rename all existing NLA tracks with the name of the action that they are holding? Tried to find some scripts but only found the one to create an NLA with the name of the active action, not to rename all the existing selected ones.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It affects all selected objects.

```
import bpy
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if ob.animation_data:
        for track in ob.animation_data.nla_tracks:
            if track.strips:
                track.name = track.strips[0].action.name
```

If you want to do only selected tracks, replace `if track.strips:` with `if track.strips and track.select:`.